# Disallowed file format product images in Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: javascript, php, oracle, magento

When I click on the upload button in product image option it shows Disallowed file format in Magento 1.9.0.1.

Comment: you should need to add this question in magneto platform https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-images?sort=newest&pageSize=50

Answer (score 0):

The SUPEE-8788 patch introduced maximum image dimensions in the configuration.

You get that error (indeed mispelled) from `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image`:

public function

```
validateUploadFile($filePath) {
    $maxDimension = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_NODE_PRODUCT_MAX_DIMENSION);
    $imageInfo = getimagesize($filePath);
    if (!$imageInfo) {
        Mage::throwException($this->__('Disallowed file type.'));
    }

    if ($imageInfo[0] > $maxDimension || $imageInfo[1] > $maxDimension) {
        Mage::throwException($this->__('Disalollowed file format.'));
    }

    $_processor = new Varien_Image($filePath);
    return $_processor->getMimeType() !== null;
}
```

By default, the maximum image dimensions is 5000px so I reckon your image upload is bigger than this.

You can change the configuration under System > Configuration > Catalog > Product Image > Maximum resolution for upload image.